# Ruby curly braces vs. do-end method chaining

Tags: ruby, method-chaining

I have found a question: [Nested Loops Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092105/nested-loops-ruby) and solved it, but the solution looks ugly (although works):

```
puts (1..10).map { |i| (i..10).step(i).inject(0) { |memo, obj| memo = memo | 2**(obj-1) } }.inject(0) { |memo, obj| memo = memo ^ obj}
```

Rewritten to multiline, but keeping curly braces:

```
puts (1..10).map { |i| 
    (i..10).step(i).inject(0) { |memo, obj| 
        memo = memo | 2**(obj-1)
        }
    }.inject { |memo, obj|
        memo = memo ^ obj
        }
```

I tried to rewrite it into multiline do-end blocks to make it more readable (knowing about the precedence difference between `{}` and `do-end`), but I get an error (I just changed the last braces):

```
puts (1..10).map { |i| 
    (i..10).step(i).inject(0) { |memo, obj| 
        memo = memo | 2**(obj-1)
        }
    }.inject do |memo, obj|
        memo = memo ^ obj
        end.to_s(2)
```

```
../../bitflipping.rb:5:in 'each': no block given (LocalJumpError)
    from ../../bitflipping.rb:5:in 'inject'
    from ../../bitflipping.rb:5:in ''
```

Is it possible to rewrite this with `do-end`? I think there is a precedence problem, how can I regroup them so for example `inject` at the end gets the block properly?

Comment: `map{|x| x}` is meaningless.

Comment: True, there was some string-to-int conversion which I just removed, and the single 'x' stayed :-) I edited the question.

Comment: Note that the error says something about `each`, but `each` doesn't appear anywhere in your code snippet. Post the code where `each` is being called.

Comment: @Kelvin: Iterators use `each` internally.

Answer (score 0):

try making it into a method, maybe?  although as sawa says, `map{|x| x}` doesn't do anything

```
def my_method 
  first_step = (1..10).map do |i| 
    (i..10).step(i).map { |x| x}.inject(0) { |memo, obj| memo = memo | 2**(obj-1) }
  end
  second_step = first_step.inject { |memo, obj| memo = memo ^ obj}.to_s(2)
  return second_step
end

puts my_method
```

Comment: Making it into a method just hides the problem :-) (also breaking it into smaller pieces would) but I just want to know if it is possible to rewrite braces to do-ends and if possible, then how (in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The syntactical construct that triggers the problem is the `puts` without parentheses.

You can fix the problem by refactoring the code so you're assigning the result to a variable (e.g. `result`) first, then doing `puts result` afterward.

Alternate solution is to wrap the entire expression in parentheses.

Here's a slimmed down reproduction of the scenarios:

```
# OK, because assignment has lower precedence than do/end 
result = (1..10).inject do |memo, obj|
  memo + obj
end
puts result

# OK because the outer parentheses resolves the ambiguity
puts(
  (1..10).inject do |memo, obj|
    memo + obj
  end
)

# ERROR: no block given
puts (1..10).inject do |memo, obj|
  memo + obj
end
```

The error happens because a `do`/`end` block has lower precedence than a method call (without parentheses).

The ERROR case is equivalent to:

```
puts( (1..10).inject ) do |memo, obj|
  memo + obj
end
```

... in other words, you're passing the block to `puts` instead of `inject`. And `inject` (at least in this case) fails because it requires a block.